# A-Frame asset sources with Webpack

Tags: webpack, aframe, src

I have set up an A-Frame project with Webpack and am trying to use files such as pngs and glbs as a-asset sources, however, I am getting 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)' error.

I've managed to get something similar working with the below code, but I'd much rather use aframe's a-assets in the scene.

body.html:

```
<a-scene>
    <a-box id="box" position="0 0.5 -4"></a-box>
</a-scene>
```

app.js:

```
import boxTex from './assets/box-tex.jpg';
function component() {
    let entity = document.getElementById('box');
    entity.setAttribute('src', boxTex);
}
component();
```